# Is there a way to uniquely identify a specific usb port on a host device?

Tags: usb, protocols, identity, host, peripherals

This question may be very broad but I'm trying to keep it platform agnostic.

If I connect a device to a USB port on a computer, is there a way for that device to uniquely identify the port it's connected to?

e.g. I have a PC with 10 USB ports. I have a smart phone that's programmed to run **Function A** if it's connected to **Port 1** and **Function B** if it's connected to **Port 2**, etc...

Is there a way that the smartphone (the peripheral in this case) can identify the specific port on the host?

Is there a way it can identify the host device as a whole?

Basically, does the peripheral know anything about the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way that the smartphone (the peripheral in this case) can identify the specific port on the host?

No, only the host knows which port a device is connected to. They all look the same from the phones point of view.

> Is there a way it can identify the host device as a whole?
>   Basically, does the peripheral know anything about the host?

Not with USB per se, but you could implement some identification in a higher protocol.

Look at later implementations of the android debugging protocol for example: The host sends an ID to the device, and unless it matches in the device database the user will be asked: "Do you want PC (ID) to be able to debug this device?"